# Coredata fetch predicate for NSSet

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsset

I have a ManagedPhoto coredata object that contains a NSSet attribute called tags. Each object in the tags set is a NSString.

I need to fetch all ManagedPhoto objects that have tags with a specific value, say 'party'. This is what I'm doing -

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"ManagedPhoto"];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.tags == 'party'"];
NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
```

But I always get an empty results array even though I know for sure that there are ManagedPhotos with tags containing 'party'. I've tried this as well -

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.tags IN %@", @[@"party"]];
```

I've tried many other things as well but nothing has worked so far! Any thought?

Comment: Is `tags` just a set of strings, or is it a *relationship* to another entity having a string property?

Comment: `tags` is just a set of strings

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To fetch objects that have *at least one* tag with the specified value, the following predicate  should work

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY tags == 'party'"]
```

or better

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY tags == %@", @"party"]
```

But I assume that the set is defined as a *transformable* property, which means that
it is stored as a binary archive in the SQLite file. Then the above queries will work
at most for objects already loaded into the managed object context, but not against
the store file.

You probably should define `tags` as a to-many relationship to another entity which has
a String property (e.g. "name") and then query with the predicate

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY tags.name == %@", @"party"]
```

Comment: Yes, the set is stored as a transformable property! And its makes sense now why it isn't working. How should I be storing the set? Thxs.

Comment: @user1656412: As a relationship, as I tried to explain in the last part of the answer.

Comment: Got it! I'll try that out. Thxs again!